# How can I make my weblogic server to reject external calls from EJBs before RUNNING state?

Tags: weblogic

I am getting a lot of Exceptions in log before RUNNING STATE because external systems are trying to make calls to this server, however, it's not completely UP yet.

I am actually out of ideas how to solve this problem. Would like to know if anyone knows any configuration in XMLs, or something in code we can do to work around this?

Comment: Can you share some of the exceptions written in the server logs plz.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a  startup delay:

In WebLogic, you can set the "StartupDelaySeconds" attribute in the server startup parameters to delay accepting requests until the application is fully initialized.

kind regards
Michel

Comment: Hey Michel, Welcome to SO,  Do you have any document link or sample example to support your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).